# What SQL command can i use to solve the following dilemma?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am creating a small database where a user can store all his workouts. I have the following tables in my database:

`UserTable(Username, Name)`, where `Username` is the primary key

`exerciseTable(ExerciseID, ExName)` where `ExerciseID` is the primary Key,

`WorkoutTable(WorkoutID, Username, Wdate, ExerciseID)`, where `WorkoutID` is the primary key and `ExerciseID` and username are the foreign keys.

I would like to output the `date` and the `ExName` for a specific user.

```
SELECT Wdate, ExerciseID
FROM WorkoutTable
WHERE Username = 'tushardev1'
```

This code will output the `date` and the `ExerciseID`. However, I do not want the `exerciseID` but the `ExerciseName` next with the `Date`. What command do I need to write to solve this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join on the `ExerciseTable`:

```
SELECT Wdate, ExName
FROM   WorkoutTable w
JOIN   ExcerciseTable e ON w.ExcerciseId = e.ExcerciseId
WHERE  username = 'tushardev1'
```